# cshtml and ascx in one MVC3 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is there something wrong to use both types of views (cshtml and ascx) in single MVC3 app? We use old-school Master with server-side form. So all views are basically .aspx. But sometimes in case of partial views it is handy to use cshtml instead of ascx.

Is it ok? Or there are some troubles in future with that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answers so far. Trying to answer by myself.
It's OK in general. All works fine. BUT! If you can use only one type (cshtml OR ascx), you have to use only one to make your project more unified.